# Export a table in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

- How do I Export a table SQL Server to
  a single flat file?  (all data and
  the first row as column names)??
- Is    there a query that do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
DECLARE  
     @saveas VARCHAR(2048)
    ,@query VARCHAR(2048)
    ,@bcpquery VARCHAR(2048)
    ,@bcpconn VARCHAR(64)
    ,@bcpdelim VARCHAR(2)

SET @query      = 'select * from table1'
SET @saveas     = '\\SERVER1\SHARE1\FOLDER\QueryOutput.txt'
SET @bcpdelim   = '|'
SET @bcpconn    = '-T' -- Trusted
--SET @bcpconn    = '-U <username> -P <password>' -- SQL authentication


SET @bcpquery = 'bcp "' + replace(@query, char(10), '') + '" QUERYOUT "' + @saveas + '" -c -t^' + @bcpdelim + ' ' + @bcpconn + ' -S ' + @@servername
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @bcpquery
```

Answer (score 13):

1. Right Click over the Database name -> Tasks -> ExportData
2. Choose the table as Data Source
3. Choose Flat file destination as destination
4. Choose a FileName
5. Mark "Column Names in the first data row"

Comment: Do you know a query that does ehat you described?

Comment: Have you considered using SSIS? Otherwise there´s an option to do it by writting an SP as described in http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/253768-Queryout-with-Column-Names.aspx and then use `EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "exec [StoredProcedure]" queryout "C:\file.txt" -T -c -t,'` to extract to a file

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if the method by pcofre always work even though that is the usual way. I have the below scenario and it broke.

I want to copy the column (tried entire table copy and Query method) value in a table to create a script for multiple servers. The issue was that the column content was varbinary and it was literally huge. The length of data accounted to 19K. It was the binary data of a PDF i had created and inserted using my ColdFusion code. Now the DBA needed to replicate the data to other environments. and he cant do a 'UPDATE/INSERT FROM ' because the data is getting truncated. so he wants me to get him the binary value from the column so that he can put it in the query analyser and run the query. It might sound silly but no matter what you did it did not work out. So I did this:

1. your_Database

   Generate Scripts

   'Choose Objects' if you have

Answer (score 2):

1. Right click on result set of `SELECT from yourTable` query
2. Choose Save Results As...