# Export image data to flat file

Tags: sql, ssis

I'm trying to export my image data from a table to a flat file using "Export Data" wizard. I've specified the query "Select picture from Profile", in SSIS to export only the data in "picture" coloumn. When I run the package, I get the following error:

> The data type for "input column
>   "picture" (26)" is DT_IMAGE, which is
>   not supported. Use DT_TEXT or DT_NTEXT
>   instead and convert the data from, or
>   to, DT_IMAGE using the data conversion
>   component.

How can I export the data to flat file

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had a similar issue: And this was my way out. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086016/export-a-table-in-sql-server-2008/9041024#9041024

Answer (score 8):

I stumbled in here from google and spent a few hours trying to find the answer. Here is what I did, assuming the column you are trying to export is 'SomeImageField':

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(max),CONVERT(varbinary(max),[SomeImageField]),2) AS SomeImageFieldAsHex FROM SomeTable;
```

This will output that column into a column named SomeImageFieldAsHex. It will be formatted as hexadecimal text.