# How to write a flat file from db containing millions of record?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I have a requirement to write a flat file out of Db data. I checked some articles but they are  providing an approach where the data is loaded into datatable first and then written to flat files. our db table contains millions of record an datatable may not work. I believe we can create a object max of 2GB size. The datatable might not be able to handle it.

What are the other approaches by which we can achieve it.

Comment: look at bulk export - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms175937.aspx  (or create an SSIS package)

Comment: What is the purpose of the export? Do you mean a flat file **database**? If so, have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086016/export-a-table-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: We need do it by program only. Creating a ssis package is a mannual process I believe.

Comment: The purpose is to have all the data in a table to a pipe delimited text file.

Comment: Did you read the documentation that @NDJ suggested? `bcp.exe` is the usual tool for generating a flat file export.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [DataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader.aspx). That is designed for these situations (high rowcount, low memory, forward only)

Comment: Yeah, That is one option . Also is there any way of achieving this by writing a stored proc ? I heard that We can use BCP (Whats that ?) but dont know how ?